# Identifying elements by constant class and dynamic id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my website I have a few elements setup in this way:
1. class='up' id='1'
2. class='up' id='2'
3. class='up' id='3'
4. class='up' id='4'
etc.. (number of elements unknown)

My problem is when trying to identify them in javascript. I tried to use the following code  (JQuery) to select a specific element:

```
$('.up#'+ id)....
```

However, this seems to fail. The `id` you see there is a variable passed into the function handling this. It is passed from a click event, and is setup this way:

```
$('.up').click(function(){
    some_function(this.id);
});
```

`some_function` accepts this id, and it is the only argument passed on to it.

I do not know why this is failing, thanks for any help!

Comment: since you have an id attribute `$('#'+ id)` will be enough

Comment: You don't need the class reference in the first code block since id should be unique. And `id` has to start with a letter, not a number.

Comment: `$('.up#'+ id)` is just a less optimal version of `$('#'+id)`, unless you have more than one element with the same `id` and want to differentiate `.up#1` vs. `.down#1`, in which case there's your problem because IDs have to be unique.

Comment: @pawel: There are use cases for `.up#id` that don't involve multiple elements with the same ID, although they're *very* rare. Basically, it's when you want to target an element with that `id` only if it has that class and ignore it if it doesn't. (And similarly with tagname qualifiers.) Again, though, it's an edge case. :-) Mostly id selectors are best on their own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CSS `id` values [cannot start with a digit](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#value-def-identifier), so the selector `.up#1` is invalid (as is the selector `#1`). If you modify your `id` values to start with a letter (I usually use `x` unless I have something more useful I can use, e.g. `x1`, `x2`, etc.), those selectors will work (provided, of course, that the elements exist as of when you're using the selector).

(This digit thing is a CSS restriction; [HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#the-id-attribute) and the DOM effectively don't care what your `id` values are, as long as they're unique.)

---

Side note: It's very rare that you want to qualify an `id` selector (with a tag name, a class, etc.). `id` values are unique on the page, and so don't need further qualification. There *are* use cases for doing so, mostly around only targeting the element *if* it also has a given tag or class and ignoring it if it doesn't, but 99.9% of the time, you just want `#id`.

Comment: I also stumbled upon this on a project. A suggestion would be to put some sort of a prefix before the numbers, like `.up#n1`.

Comment: Not in HTML5: "Any string, with the following restrictions:
must be at least one character long
must not contain any space characters"
http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id

Comment: @pawel: Right. CSS and HTML5 are different things. The problem here is a CSS selector.

Comment: Since we're in the context of DOM querying this should not be a problem then.

Comment: @pawel: No. Again: It's a **CSS** selector, and so must follow the rules of a CSS selector. You can check this yourself trivially: In Chrome's or Firefox's web console, type `document.querySelector("#1")` and see what it does.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This would mean that jQuery delegates `$('.foo#bar')` to `querySelector`, but `$('#bar')` to `getElementById`, which I can not reproduce. But that's technicalities, of course it's better to be safe and add that letter to ID :)

Comment: @pawel: What jQuery does with selectors varies widely on the selector you use, on the browser, and what version of jQuery you're using. It doesn't always follow the rules, but it does use `getElementById` for simple `id` selectors (and `getElementById` doesn't use CSS selectors, so it doesn't care about the `id`). [According to the docs](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/), jQuery will also use `getElementById` even if you combine an `id` selector with something else, which surprises me and also makes me wonder what version of jQuery the OP is using, as he/she said this solved the problem. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I'm familiar with Sizzle selector engine, that's why I'm surprised, especially that isolated test cases work fine for a variety of selectors with single-digit ID attribute.

Comment: @pawel: Me too. Bottom-line for me, though, is not to use invalid selectors, even when they (sometimes) work. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You should put a character in front of the `id`, like this.

```
<element id="e1" class="up">

$('#e' + id) //reference the element by id
```